# Does Windows Server 2019 Essentials have to be a domain controller as requirement?

Tags: windows

I plan to install and deploy a Windows Server 2019 Essentials machine for a very small business with up to 10 employees.

I have read somewhere that Windows Server 2019 Essentials have to be the only and primary domain controller in a Windows Server environment which is okay.

But do I **need** to install a domain controller or can I run it without one if it's not needed?

Comment: You should only have one Essentials server in your domain. it must hold the master FSMO roles. You can add member sevrers but they should not be other Essentials servers. Your additional server will need CALs. Be warned, Windows Server core licensing is expensive. Go down this route with them carefully. You might just be best off making sure their server is pretty beefy with a decent backup strategy. OR keep the server ticking over and only use it for user management, but then use the likes of Office365/SharePoint Online if they plan to need a central repository for company data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't have to be configured as a domain controller, but can be so configured.

The Microsoft blog
[Windows Server 2019 Essentials update](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/windowsserver/2018/09/05/windows-server-2019-essentials-update/)
has this to say:

> **If configured as a Domain Controller**, Windows Server 2019 Essentials must be the only Domain Controller, must run all Flexible Single Master Operations (FSMO) roles, and cannot have two-way trusts with other Active Directory domains.

In short, configuring it as domain controller will have drastic consequences for
the network in which it is found.

I strongly advise to skip Windows Server 2019 Essentials and get instead
Windows Server 2016 Essentials.

The article
[Windows Server 2019 Essentials – end of an era!](https://www.theofficemaven.com/news/windows-server-2019-essentials)
says this:

> While Microsoft will still be releasing an “Essentials” SKU for Windows Server 2019, it will be completely devoid of everything that we recognize as being part of Windows Server Essentials in its current form.
>
> Basically, Microsoft is releasing their first (and last) non-essentials Windows Server Essentials release that is completely gutted of anything even remotely resembling Windows Server Essentials as we currently know it. And obviously, without the underlying “Essentials” bits, there can be no more new WSE RemoteApp or WSE WorkFolders product releases going forward.
>
> My suggestion to those who want to continue running an on-premises Essentials server would be to grab up as many Windows Server 2016 (Standard, Datacenter, or Essentials) licenses as you possibly can (before they’re all gone), and then ride it out with that particular version for as long as Microsoft will be providing support for it (see: [Windows Server 2016 Essentials servicing timeline](https://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search?alpha=Windows%20Server%202016%20Essentials)).

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft documentation [is unclear](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-essentials/install/add-windows-server-essentials-as-a-member-server):

> Title: Add Windows Server Essentials as a Member Server
>
> Note: Windows Server Essentials can only be deployed as domain controller. **In this document, Windows Server Essentials does not include Windows Server Essentials.**

However, one of the pages about ["what's new in Server 2016 Essentials"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-essentials/install/add-windows-server-essentials-as-a-member-server) has this note:

> Windows server 2012 R2 Essentials supports only one domain per server, which is required, and the Essentials server must be the root of the forest. While a domain and forest are still required, the Windows Server 2016 Essentials Experience role can now be deployed on Windows Server 2016 Standard or Datacenter to support multiple domains.

This seems to say:

1. Yes, the Essentials server requires an Active Directory domain.

   (However, in any case, there's no requirement for *clients* to be domain members or care about the domain at all.)
2. The "one domain controller" limitation only exists in Essentials 2012, not in later releases.

Comment: You used a link pertaining to Windows Server 2016 Essentials, not 2019, but the 2019 version has departed sharply from its predecessors. I suggest deleting this answer.